# Explain intuitively, not mathematically why $\nabla^2 u = 0 \implies \oint \nabla u \cdot \tilde{n} \, ds = 0$

Tags: surface-integrals, divergence-operator, line-integrals

> With $u$ as heat, explain intuitively, not mathematically why $\nabla^2 u = 0 \implies \oint \nabla u \cdot \tilde{n} \, ds = 0$

Mathematically, this is a direct application of the divergence theorem. That says that for any vector field $F$:

\begin{align*}
  \iiint_R \nabla F \, dV &= \oint (F \cdot \tilde{n}) \, dS \\
\end{align*}

Where $F = \nabla u$, we have:

\begin{align*}
  \iiint_R \nabla^2 u \, dV &= \oint (\nabla u \cdot \tilde{n}) \, dS \\
\end{align*}

Combining with the given of $\nabla^2 u = 0$ yields:

\begin{align*}
  \iiint_R \nabla^2 u \, dV &= \oint (\nabla u \cdot \tilde{n}) \, dS = 0 \\
\end{align*}

The equation $\nabla^2 u = 0$ means constant heat flow at every position.

The equation $\oint (\nabla u \cdot \tilde{n}) \, dS = 0$ means that all heat coming in equals all heat going out.

I don't see logically why the first implies the second. Can't temperature be rising or falling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually for the heat flow the [continuity equation (ce)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation#Energy_and_heat) is $\frac{ \partial u}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot F = 0$

And the temperature will stop raising or failing when there is a [steady state (ss)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steady_state) $\frac{ \partial u}{\partial t}=0$

Only then you can have what you want $\oint (\nabla u \cdot \tilde{n}) \ dS =\iiint_R \nabla^2 u\ dV= \iiint_R \nabla\cdot F\ dV =_{ce}\iiint_R -\frac{ \partial u}{\partial t}\ dV=_{ss}0$

Hope it helps